# Is the new Ubuntu 21.10 compatible with 32-bit (for termux)?

Tags: 32-bit, arm

I recently received a 64-bit version of new Ubuntu daily builds. You can download Ubuntu 21.10 daily builds from the Ubuntu website.
You will be able to download Ubuntu 21.10 on October 14, 2021. This date is the one listed on Launchpad, the home of Ubuntu development.

Does the new version of Ubuntu (21.10) have a 32-bit version (`armhf` architecture), which can be installed on Android phones within Termux?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: Hey, does the Ubuntu 21.10 base `armhf` image have the same issue as in 21.04 when you run `sudo apt update`? This issue: https://askubuntu.com/q/1336219/124466

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for 32bit ARM, i.e. the `armhf` architecture, which Ubuntu 21.10 does support.

However, Ubuntu does not anymore support the traditional  32bit (`i386`) architecture, as Thomas Ward mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Got pulled off for a work call so I couldn't hit "Save" on my edit which included the ARM bits, sorry!  Good catch though

Comment: I happened to want to use this tag, but I got this error message، ```Creating the new tag 'armhf' requires at least 300 reputation```

Comment: @BullShit Ask a question in Ask Ubuntu Meta, and the moderators may want to create it.

Answer (score 2):

**32-bit ARM**

ARM 32bit is supported by all current releases (and currently, all future releases) of Ubuntu, and can be installed in Termux once their system catches up with cloud releases.

However, this is limited to devices with the `armhf` infrastructure instruction set specifically - it will not work for older `armel` devices or devices that don't speak armhf in the right endianness.

---

**32-bit non-ARM**

There are no Ubuntu versions that support standard 32-bit.  This includes all current and all FUTURE Ubuntu versions.

The last supported version of Ubuntu that was 32bit was (only just barely) Ubuntu 18.04.  Since 18.04, there are no 32bit ISOs/images anymore.