# apt mirror:// ubuntu-ports

Tags: apt, software-sources, arm64, apt-mirror

I am trying to configure my sources.list using the mirror:// method on ubuntu arm64:

```
mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt
```

only works for amd64 but not arm.

Any equivalent of this for arm64?

Answer (score 2):

No, but there are some mirrors.

Using a script in [Are there alternative repositories to ports.ubuntu.com for ARM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428698/are-there-alternative-repositories-to-ports-ubuntu-com-for-arm) I found only 10.

```
./find-mirrors.sh arm64 jammy main https 4
Valid: https://mirror.kumi.systems/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://ubuntu-ports.mirror.net.in/
Valid: https://in.mirror.coganng.com/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://mirror.nishi.network/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://jp.mirror.coganng.com/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://mirror.misakamikoto.network/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://ubuntu-mirror.cloud.mu/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://mirror.coganng.com/ubuntu-ports/
Valid: https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/ubuntu-ports/
```

So while you can use one of them, you cannot (currently) use the `mirror://` format to load-balance between them

Comment: Really? Some mirrors provide /ubuntu-ports/.

Comment: https://mirror.coganng.com/ubuntu-ports/ one example here.

Comment: There are some but there's not an auto mirror list like there is for amd64. I'll update the answer.

Comment: As per my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463774/nala-broke-my-apt-package-manager/1463777#1463777), remember that all the national archives/mirrors (e.g. `dk.archive.ubuntu.com)` are also in fact mirrors that hold both the `ubuntu` and `ubuntu-ports` packages. However, I don't know if that's applicable in this particular situation.