# Nala broke my apt package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, nala

I wanted to try out nala un my Kubuntu 22.04 OS. I ran `sudo apt search nala` and saw that nala was available in apt, so i ran `sudo apt install nala` . I then ran `sudo nala fetch`, because that is what many youtubers were running. I selected the first 3 mirrors that were the fasted and then ran `sudo nala update` and i got errors. I then ran `sudo apt update` to check if that was only the problem with nala, but no, it was with apt. Maybe the fetch command broke something? Here are the errors:

```
Get:1 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:2 http://mirror.eu-fr.kamatera.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                      
Hit:3 http://me.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://me.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                  
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                      
Hit:6 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                          
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease                                                         
Get:8 http://me.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                       
Ign:9 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                         
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flexiondotorg/obs-fully-loaded/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:11 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                          
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                  
Err:13 http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                               
  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.53.177.54 80]
Hit:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                
Ign:15 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages      
Get:16 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1395 kB]
Get:17 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en_GB [483 kB]
Get:18 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [510 kB]
Get:19 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [423 kB]
Get:20 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [100.0 kB]                     
Get:21 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [148 kB]                    
Get:22 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15.8 kB]               
Get:23 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [311 kB]
Get:24 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [30.3 kB]                 
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]                  
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]          
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]          
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]          
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]          
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]                                
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]                                
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Get:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [30.4 kB]
Ign:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages  
Ign:50 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages        
Ign:51 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages      
Ign:15 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages            
Ign:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages      
Ign:50 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages        
Ign:51 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages      
Ign:15 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages            
Ign:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages      
Ign:50 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages        
Ign:51 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages      
Ign:15 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages       
Ign:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages    
Ign:50 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages         
Ign:51 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:50 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:51 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:15 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 143.205.176.63 80]
Ign:25 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:50 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:51 http://ubuntu.uni-klu.ac.at/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:33 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                   
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.53.177.54 80]
E: The repository 'http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have already removed nala from my pc using `sudo apt remove nala` and `sudo apt purge nala` but i get the same errors. Thanks for your help.

Edit: i saw some other similar questions and did what @kanehekili said, i saw the mirrors listed in KDE Discover in settings and i am not seeing the errors anymore  . Hope that is not a temporary fix.

Comment: Remove your repository: `http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease`. That is one culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nala creates its own `nala-sources.list` file located at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nala-sources.list`. This is documented for the [`nala fetch`](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/blob/main/docs/nala-fetch.8.rst) command.

##### Default approach

For Ubuntu, Nala parses the list found at `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors-rss`. However, it's possible that some of these mirrors may be returning errors like you experienced (which should only happen in extremely rare cases). But this will be explicitly stated in the `apt` output, so that you can easily disable that particular mirror.

In this case, either manually remove the mirror from `nala-sources.list`, or run `nala fetch` again, and select other mirrors, without the one giving errors.

*Please note:* Special attention must be paid to the mirror list if you're using any other architecture than `x64` (for instance `arm64` on a Raspberry Pi), in which case the mirror must be hosting `ubuntu-ports`. Use [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428698/are-there-alternative-repositories-to-ports-ubuntu-com-for-arm) to find out which mirrors include the ports, and build your `nala-sources.list` from these mirrors.

##### Custom approach

Another approach I've recently followed is to simply use the default national mirrors from your neighboring countries as Nala mirrors. In this way you're sure that it's only the official mirrors that are used, and an added bonus is that they also provide both `updates`, `security` and `backports` branches as well - *AND* they also provide `ubuntu-ports` for other architectures.

So I've done the following: In my normal `sources.list`, I use the main repo `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`, but I reside in Denmark.

Then, my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nala-sources.list` goes like this:

```
# Sources file built for nala

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

So I use the mirrors from Denmark, Germany Norway and Sweden as additional Nala sources. This means Nala can do parallel downloads from the neighboring countries, and the chance that the official national mirror throws an `apt` error should be very small.