Repo 404 issue: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on ARM64 (Raspberry Pi 5)

wrote out the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with rpi-imager to an USB SSD.
It installed OK, working on a Raspberry Pi 5 with the USB SSD plugged in (microSD cards are weak..).

But if I issue a plain "apt-get update", then i get this:
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [89.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [89.7 kB]
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Translation-en [513 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Components [460 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Icons (48x48) [106 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64) [156 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64@2) [21.8 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [30.0 kB]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages    
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Translation-en [5982 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Components [3573 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (48x48) [3717 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (64x64) [7747 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (64x64@2) [75.0 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [295 kB]
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages 
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted Translation-en [18.7 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 c-n-f Metadata [412 B]
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Translation-en [118 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Components [31.6 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (48x48) [56.1 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (64x64) [186 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (64x64@2) [904 B]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [7152 B]
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages 
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [6704 B]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [108 B]
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe Translation-en [4524 B]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main Translation-en [6544 B]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [108 B]
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe Translation-en [3672 B]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/restricted arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages        
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Err:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Fetched 23.6 MB in 4s (5503 kB/s)

** (appstreamcli:3555): WARNING **: 15:24:19.985: No origin found for file ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_noble_main_dep11_Components-arm64.yml.gz

** (appstreamcli:3555): WARNING **: 15:24:19.985: No origin found for file ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_noble_universe_dep11_Components-arm64.yml.gz

** (appstreamcli:3555): WARNING **: 15:24:19.985: No origin found for file ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_noble_multiverse_dep11_Components-arm64.yml.gz
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::102 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
# 

The Question: is this a temporary issue? Or manual workaround needed as permanent fix? I don't think this is normal. They are missing the ARM64 packages in Ubuntu 24 LTS?
I sent mail to the official mirror bug mail: [rt.ubuntu.com #82727] - will update if they reply.
Using the default config.. eg.: apt sources:
# cat ubuntu.sources 
Types: deb
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main universe restricted multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

## Ubuntu security updates. Aside from URIs and Suites,
## this should mirror your choices in the previous section.
Types: deb
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main universe restricted multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
# 

If i use the find_mirros script from Are there alternative repositories to ports.ubuntu.com for ARM? then the best looks like "http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/", the output:
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Get:2 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
Get:3 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [89.7 kB]
Hit:4 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Get:5 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [89.7 kB]
Ign:6 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Get:7 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main Translation-en [513 kB]
Get:8 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Components [460 kB]
Get:9 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main Icons (48x48) [106 kB]
Get:10 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64) [156 kB]
Get:11 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main Icons (64x64@2) [21.8 kB]
Get:12 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [30.0 kB]
Ign:13 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages   
Get:14 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe Translation-en [5982 kB]
Get:15 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Components [3573 kB]           
Get:16 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (48x48) [3717 kB]
Get:17 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (64x64) [7747 kB]
Get:18 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe Icons (64x64@2) [75.0 kB]
Get:19 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [295 kB]
Ign:20 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages 
Get:21 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted Translation-en [18.7 kB]
Get:22 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 c-n-f Metadata [412 B]
Ign:23 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages                      
Get:24 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Translation-en [118 kB]
Get:25 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Components [31.6 kB]            
Get:26 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (48x48) [56.1 kB]               
Get:27 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (64x64) [186 kB]                
Get:28 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Icons (64x64@2) [904 B]          
Get:29 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [7152 B]      
Ign:30 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Get:31 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main Translation-en [6704 B]
Get:32 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [108 B]
Ign:33 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                
Get:34 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe Translation-en [4524 B]       
Get:35 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]  
Get:36 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/restricted arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:37 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Ign:38 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                   
Get:39 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main Translation-en [6544 B]
Get:40 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [108 B]       
Ign:41 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages               
Get:42 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe Translation-en [3672 B]
Get:43 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:44 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/restricted arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:45 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Ign:6 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages                         
Ign:13 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages          
Ign:20 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:6 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:13 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:20 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:23 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:38 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:33 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:6 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages                                                                     
Ign:20 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages                                                                   
Ign:23 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages                                                                   
Ign:30 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages                                                                 
Ign:38 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                
Ign:41 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                            
Ign:33 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                                             
Ign:38 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                
Ign:41 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                            
Ign:6 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages                                                                           
Ign:13 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages                                                                      
Ign:20 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:23 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:30 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages                                                                  
Ign:33 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                                              
Ign:6 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages                                                                          
Ign:13 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages                                                                     
Ign:20 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages                                                                   
Ign:23 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages                                                                   
Ign:30 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages                                                                 
Ign:38 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                 
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                             
Ign:33 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                                             
Ign:38 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                
Ign:41 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                            
Ign:6 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages                                                                          
Ign:13 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages                                                                     
Ign:20 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages                                                                   
Ign:23 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages                                                                   
Ign:30 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages                                                                 
Ign:33 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                                             
Ign:38 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                
Ign:41 https://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                            
Ign:6 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages                                                                           
Ign:13 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages                                                                      
Err:6 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/main arm64 Packages                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2602:2ea::93 443]
Ign:20 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/restricted arm64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:23 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse arm64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:30 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages                                                                  
Ign:33 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                                              
Ign:38 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                 
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                             
37% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                     3860 kB/s 20sE: Transaction http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
Err:13 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble/universe arm64 Packages                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 2602:2ea::93 443]
Err:30 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main arm64 Packages                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 2602:2ea::93 443]
37% [Waiting for headers]                                                                                                     3860 kB/s 20sE: Transaction http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
Err:33 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2602:2ea::93 443]
Err:38 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/main arm64 Packages                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2602:2ea::93 443]
E: Transaction http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
Err:41 http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe arm64 Packages                                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2602:2ea::93 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                              
E: Transaction http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
E: Transaction http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
E: Transaction http://ubuntu.macarne.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
# 
# apt-get install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gimp
# 

if i try to use the "https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/" then:
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:4 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:5 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:4 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:5 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:4 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:5 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Err:2 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.36). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:https:
Err:4 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:https:
Err:5 https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:https:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.36). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:https:
W: Failed to fetch https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:https:
W: Failed to fetch https://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:https:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
# apt-get install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gimp
# 

update: even usin plain https it is 404
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Err:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
# 

update: Paul Collins via RT:

The URL for the ports repository is as follows:
http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports

but after updating, it is still bad.. https://pastebin.com/raw/wRqdNN1S same 404 issue like after the default install

thanks, but no, these 404's are on the main ubuntu repos, i cannot even install a basic openssh-server on ARM64 in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS now! is this a global outage for the repos for ARM64?

lol, still no solution. so a default install of an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS to ARM64 VMs are bad... they produce http 404. no one ever noticed this? no one is using ARM64 with Ubuntu eg.: on a rpi5? i cannot even install vim due to the 404

Apt can't find packages on Ubuntu 20.04 arm64 (Raspberry Pi 4)
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo apt update
+
have repo as: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports


ARM64 is inot in the main repos.  It's in the ports repository.
Only amd64 and i386 architectures are in the main archive repositories.  Use ports.ubuntu.com instead of archive.ubuntu.com in your source declarations.  It should then behave.

i changed to ports from archive, apt-get clean, apt-get update, but having the exact same issue. same for the find_mirrors for ARM64: https://askubuntu.com/questions/428698/are-there-alternative-repositories-to-ports-ubuntu-com-for-arm wow.

@peterK88 add your updated 404 and apt update output when you use ports to your question as an edit.

updated the question, thanks. now it gives a differrent error message, maybe due to that i used the find_mirror script too much and i got temporary banned? :D

i mailed the mirror supporting guys [rt.ubuntu.com #82727] will update if they answer anything.

@peterK88 Use http:// for ports.  It's possible whatever mirror you're seeing does NOT have HTTPS on it (connection refused means no HTTPS listener on that URL)

thanks! but now we are back to the original 404 error :D
